# Get oAuth token manually for social login

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth

I am trying to get an `oAuth token` manually for social login so that I can test some functionality in the backend of my app - namely calling some REST APIs by mocking a user that has logged in via Secure Social Login (SSL). This involves calling `<oAuth tenant url>/api/v2/userinfo`. I began looking at the [Authorization Code Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?shell#authorization-code-flow44) but this requires an `/authorize` call which redirects rather than returns an `access_code` (for example).

So then I thought that the [Token Exchange for Native Social](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?shell#token-exchange-for-native-social) documentation would be how to do so but I'm not sure about some of the parameters.

> curl --request POST 
> --url 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token' 
> --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
> --data 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange&subject_token=SUBJECT_TOKEN&subject_token_type=SUBJECT_TOKEN_TYPE&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&audience=API_IDENTIFIER&scope=SCOPE'
> }'

> subject_token: Externally-issued identity artifact, representing the user.
> subject_token_type: Identifier that indicates the type of subject_token. Currently supported native social values are: http://auth0.com/oauth/token-type/apple-authz-code.

I thought that the `subject_token` could be the `user_id` from the resource, e.g. `google-oauth2|122013643367342457857` but I am not at all sure what the `subject_token_type` should be. The application (in `oAuth`) is a 'Single Page Application'.

Comment: Hey there, did you figure this out?

Comment: @Hášíl Páůďýál Unfortunately I didn't - sorry. I'm finding this site less useful recently

Comment: No worries, I also didnt find any way to generate access_token for my users. There used to be an impersonate api but its deprecated. On your question you mentioned about /authorize, if you are requesting response type token, then you will finally get access_token. If interested check <auth tenant>/.well-known/openid-configuration under response_types_supported for /authorize endpoint